# How to get Command Functionality from a Panel

Tags: asp.net

Is there a `Panel` or any container with `CommandName`, `CommandArguments` instead of using Buttons (LinkButton, ImageButton, ...)?

I want to add a column in a GridView to make selection for the row, the whole cell's rectangle instead of a Select link.

Answer (score 1):

You can make (almost) anything implement `CommandName` and `CommandArguments` by implementing the `IButtonControl` interface. You will probably also want to implement the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface.

[This article](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2009/05/14/Implementing-IPostBackEventHandler-in-an-ASPNET-Control.aspx) covers in detail exactly what you are asking about, generally: making a `Panel` into a command control. It's not entirely trivial.

But making a table row clickable is a lot easier, though, esp. using jQuery. See [this article.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/) You just bind an event to the row, and go from there. In this example, they're redirecting to the url for a link in the row on a click event. You could just as easily do something else like call `__doPostBack` to cause an async postback and run arbitrary server code, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way how you can make a GridView-Cell as Sort-Column(see in RowCreated, the rest is sample-data):

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindGridView()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindGridView()
        Dim source As New List(Of String)(New String() {"1. row", "2. row", "3. row", "4. row", "5. row"})
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = source
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
        Dim cell As New TableCell
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            cell.Text = "select"
            cell.ToolTip = "click to select row"
            cell.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';"
            cell.Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(DirectCast(sender, GridView), "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        End If
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell)
    End Sub
```

**Edit**: if you get a "Invalid postback or callback argument"-Exception from ASP.Net, you can either set `EnableEventValidation="False"` or add following to your page's codebehind:

```
   Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(GridView1.UniqueID, "Select$" & row.RowIndex)
            End If
        Next
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End Sub
```

If you need C#, copy all into: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/